# How to generate a random 3D point with a distance to a given plane?

Tags: c#, math, random, 3d

I have a plane from 3 points (triangle). How can I generate a random point to this plane with a specified distance? The projection of the generated point should also be within the triangle.

Comment: just generate a random point on the plane and move the given distance from it

Answer (score 2):

Let's we have non-collinear points A, B, C.
1. Generate two random values t and u in range 0..1. We can use these values to get uniform distribution in parallelogram formed by vectors AB and AC. To get uniform distribution in triangle, we reflect points which hit the second triangle, about parallelogram diagonal (if-branch of pseudocode)

[image]

```
t = random ( 0, 1 ) 
u = random ( 0, 1 )
if (t + u > 1 ) then
   t = 1 - t
   u = 1 - u
```

2. Make random point P inside triangle ABC:

`P = A + t * AB + u * AC`

3. Move P away off ABC plane

   `n = normalized(AB x AC)` (vector product)

   `P' = P + d * n`

where d - needed distance

Comment: Good answer, but please elaborate on the way you are uniformly sampling the triangle. The reflection about the line `t + u = 1` should be explained.